# Spark reduceBykey works poorly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm writing a program on Spark in scala. It's used to count the numbers of keys. Here is the data example:

```
 Name     Fruit         Place
 A        apple         China
 A        apple         China
 A        apple         U.S
 A        banana        U.K
 B        apple         Japan
 B        orange        Chile
 C        apple         French
```

It's a data frame of many columns but I only care about the above three columns, so there may be some repeated records. I would like to count, for example, the number of production places of the fruit eaten by A.

```
val res = data.select("name","fruit","place")
.map(v=>((v.getString(0),v.getString(1)),ArrayBuffer(v.getString(2)))).rdd.reduceByKey((a,b)=>a++=b)
.map(v=>(v._1._1,Map(v._1._2 -> v._2.toSet.size))).reduceByKey((a,b)=>a++=b)
```

I first select the columns I need and  then use ("name", "fruit") as the key to collect the production places in one ArrayBuffer for each kind of fruit eaten by each person. Then I use "name" as the key to collect the number of production places for each fruit in a map like {"apple": 2}. So the result is informally like RDD[("name",Map("fruit"->"places count"))].

In the program I did this kind of work about **3 times** to calculate information similar to the above example. For example, to compute the number of different fruits in one production places eaten by each person.

The size of the data is about 80GB and I run the job on 50 executors. Each executor has 4 cores and memory of 24GB. Moreover the data is repartitioned into 200 partitions. So this job should be finished in a very short period of time as I expected. However, it took me more than one day to run the job and failed because of  ***org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 10*** and ***java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded***.

I did a lot of things to optimize this program, like reset the spark.mesos.executor.memoryOverhead  and use mutable map to minimize the GC cost of frequently creating and cleaning objects. I even try to use reduceByKey to move the data with the same key into one partition to boost the performance, but with little help. The code is like:

```
val new_data = data.map(v=>(v.getAs[String]("name"),ArrayBuffer((v.getAs[String]("fruit"),v.getAs[String]("place"))))) 
 .rdd.reduceByKey((a,b)=>a++=b).cache()
```

Then I don't need to shuffle the data each time I do similar calculations. And the later work can be done on the basis of new_data. However, it seems that this optimization doesn't work.

**Finally, I found that there is about 50% of the data has the same value on the field "name", say "H". I removed the data with name "H" and the job finished in 1 hour.**

**Here is my question:**

1. Why the distribution of keys has such a great impact on the performance of reduceByKey? I use the word "distribution" to express the number of occurrences of different keys. In my case, the size of the data is not big but one key dominates the data so the performance is greatly affected. I assume it's the problem of reduceByKey, am I wrong?
2. If I have to reserve the records with name "H", how to avoid the performance issue?
3. Is it possible to use reduceByKey to repartition the data and put the records with the same key ("name") into one partition?
4. Is it really help to move the records with the same key ("name") to one partition to improve the performance? I know it may cause memory issue but I have to run similar code in the program several times, so I guess it may help in the later work. Am I right?

Thanks for help!

Comment: My best guess is that when you reduce by key, all the records with name "H" are sent to one node (40GB of data!) and then that one node tries to work through it all (with a good chunk of data overflowed onto the disk)

Comment: @bendl thanks for the comment. Yeah I think so, but even there are 40GB of the data, the memory of the executor is 24GB, which means it shouldn't be that slow (more than 1 day). Do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to avoid the big shuffle is to first do a data frame from fruit to places.

```
val fruitToPlaces = data.groupBy("fruit").agg(collect_set("place").as("places"))
```

This data frame should be small (i.e. fits in memory)
You do `fruitToPlaces.cache.count` to make sure it's ok

Then you do a join on fruit.

```
data.join(fruitToPlaces, Seq("fruit"), "left_outer")
```

Spark should be smart enough to do a hash join (and not a shuffle join)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it seems to be a little different from what I want to get. In your case, the guys who have eaten the same kinds of fruits will always get the same set of places. However, it's not true, someone may just have the apple from U.S not any other places.